# Data conversion issue in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs, denodo

I am trying to create a view in Oracle EBS database from different tables, and the view has few columns that are calculated type particularly there are two columns in which the base tables are off combination of varchar type and number type and the resulting view has the type as Number type for this two columns I have tried to avoid errors while data conversion from type two number type by using

```
TO_NUMBER(revenue, DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR)
```

And if this view is queried, I’m getting the results in oracle as expected, but when trying to query from DVS like Denodo I am seeing an error that there is a non-numeric type in place where a numeric type is expected for these two row. if I remove these two columns, I am able to get the results perfectly on the Denodo side but when I include these two columns, I am getting the same error. I’ve tried various options, but no luck, but when the view is converted as a table on the Oracle side, and queried from DENODO it is working fine. I don’t understand where the issue is.

The calculated columns in the view are :

```
DECODE (
                SIGN (expenditure_item_date - TO_DATE ('20-JUN-2010')),
                1,    DECODE (
                           attribute7,
                           NULL, DECODE (trans_source,
                                         'Payroll', quantity,
                                         'Eff_Report', quantity,
                                         'Shops', quantity,
                                         0),
                           TO_NUMBER (attribute7 DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR)),
                NVL (quantity, 0))
```

and

```
DECODE (
                SIGN (expenditure_item_date - TO_DATE ('20-JUN-2010')),
                1, NVL (quantity, 0),
                DECODE (
                    attribute7,
                    NULL, DECODE (trans_source,
                                  'Payroll', quantity,
                                  'Eff_Report, quantity,
                                  'Shops', quantity,
                                  0),
                   TO_NUMBER(attribute7 DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR)))
```

FYI `attribute7` is of `varchar` type and `quantity` is of `Number` type.

When the view is queried from Denodo, I am getting

> [JDBC ROUTE] [ERROR] Received exception with message 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected'

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE VIEW` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data that would allow us to replicate the problem. The error is an Oracle error so, if you have the same data and same query parameters then you should be able to replicate the issue in the database independently of the third-party application you are using to connect to the database. If not then you need to debug what the difference is between the queries Denodo is sending to the database to the queries you are using and include that in the question.

Comment: The second" 'Eff_Report, quantity, " is missing a quote, it's either a typo in your post either it's the source of the problem...

Answer (score 1):

That error is not coming from the `TO_NUMBER()` calls, it's coming from the `TO_DATE()` calls.

The [ORA-01858 error](https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-01858/) is described as:

> **Cause**
> The input data to be converted using a date format model was incorrect. The input data did not contain a number where a number was required by the format model.
>
> **Action**
> Fix the input data or the date format model to ensure that the elements match the number and type. Retry the operation.

So the issue is the *date format model*, which you have not provided, so it's using an implicit format model, not the number conversion part.

Doing `TO_DATE ('20-JUN-2010')` relies on your sessions' NLS settings, and those are different in the two clients/applications where you are testing this. That applies to the date format model, causing this error, and (as you are using a month abbreviation) the date language.

You could do a more explicit conversion:

```
SIGN (expenditure_item_date - TO_DATE ('20-JUN-2010', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'))
```

but with a fixed value it would be simpler to use a date literal:

```
SIGN (expenditure_item_date - DATE '2010-06-20'),
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UtxtV8Mw)

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment but you can simplify your query using `CASE` rather than nested `DECODE`s and inverting some of the conditions:

```sql
CASE
WHEN expenditure_item_date <= DATE '2010-06-20' OR expenditure_item_date IS NULL
THEN COALESCE(quantity, 0)
WHEN attribute7 IS NOT NULL
THEN TO_NUMBER (attribute7 DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR))
WHEN trans_source IN ('Payroll', 'Eff_Report', 'Shops')
THEN quantity
ELSE 0
END
```